# Como retirar alguns dados de um JSON e exibir somente o restante?

Tags: php, json, echo

Olá, quero imprimir alguns dados de uma página JSON em PHP, por exemplo:

Tenho essa página aqui http://hts03.kshost.com.br:8642/statistics?json=1

JSON:

```
{
    "totalstreams": 1,
    "activestreams": 1,
    "currentlisteners": 19,
    "peaklisteners": 57,
    "maxlisteners": 500,
    "uniquelisteners": 18,
    "averagetime": 881,
    "version": "2.2.1.109 (posix(linux x64))",
    "streams": [{
        "id": 1,
        "currentlisteners": 19,
        "peaklisteners": 57,
        "maxlisteners": 500,
        "uniquelisteners": 18,
        "averagetime": 881,
        "servergenre": "� s� granada na cara da concorrencia",
        "serverurl": "http:\/\/www.habbonados.com.br",
        "servertitle": "gabrielsa441",
        "songtitle": "Wiz Khalifa - See You Again ft. Charlie Puth [Official Video] Furious 7 Soundtrack",
        "irc": "https:\/\/www.habbo.com.br\/hotel?room=81601237",
        "icq": "NA",
        "aim": "NA",
        "streamhits": 2493,
        "streamstatus": 1,
        "backupstatus": 0,
        "streampath": "\/",
        "streamuptime": 645,
        "bitrate": 64,
        "content": "audio\/aacp"
    }]
}
```

Quero tirar esses dados dela:

```
"uniquelisteners":10,
"averagetime":462,
"servergenre":"� s� granada na cara da concorrencia"
```

E passar pra uma página em PHP com o echo

Comment: Coloque os dados do link externo na pergunta por favor. Com a `formatação`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A forma mais direta seria essa:

```
<?php
$url = 'http://hts03.kshost.com.br:8642/statistics?json=1';
$dados = json_decode(file_get_contents($url));
```

Agora a variável "$dados" tem todas as informações do JSON, vc escreve como quiser na tela.

Comment: Aparece uma página em branco, `var_dump($dados)` = Null

Comment: Como eu faço pra escrever como eu quiser na página? Por exemplo fazer imprimir só um dado

Comment: FilippeSims, dá uma olhada na resposta do @Miguel

Answer (score 5):

Olhe faça assim, havia um problema na *character encoding*, temos de fazer [utf8_encoding](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.utf8-encode.php):

```
<?php
$jsonRaw = file_get_contents('http://hts03.kshost.com.br:8642/statistics?json=1');
$jsonParsed = json_decode(utf8_encode($jsonRaw), true);

echo($jsonParsed['uniquelisteners']). '<br>';
echo($jsonParsed['averagetime']). '<br>';
echo($jsonParsed['streams'][0]['servergenre']). '<br>';
```

Tem aqui uma solução usando [curl](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.curl.php):

```
<?php
function get_data($url) {
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, True);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.7; rv:7.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/7.0.1');
    $return = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    return $return;
}

$jsonRaw = get_data('http://hts03.kshost.com.br:8642/statistics?json=1');
$jsonParsed = json_decode(utf8_encode($jsonRaw), true);

echo($jsonParsed['uniquelisteners']). '<br>';
echo($jsonParsed['averagetime']). '<br>';
echo($jsonParsed['streams'][0]['servergenre']). '<br>';
```

Comment: Funcionou, MUITO obrigado!

Comment: deves decidir qual a resposta correta.